# What is the deal with this weird poop and white fly?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

This poop appears to have something embedded in it that I really *hope* is not corn, and some sort of white fly flying around it.

What's up with this poop?

[image: Shiny poop and ghost fly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white fly is an eternal fly, and will hurt you if it touches you. Additionally, if the poop is destroyed, the eternal fly will be reincarnated as a tougher red fly.

You must choose for yourself whether or not to disturb the eternal fly's slumber - as far as I can tell, its drops are identical to normal poops.